# D3 Topojson Adding Name Property to FeatureCollection

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have hard-coded a merged multipolygon region by filtering the desired FIPS ids like so:

```
var set1 = d3.set([
  48111, 48421, 48195, 48357, 48295, 48205, 48341, 48233, 48393, 48211,
  48359, 48375, 48065, 48179, 48483, 48485, 48077, 48337, 48237, 48009,
  48503, 48023, 48269, 48125, 48107, 48303, 48219, 48079, 48501, 48445,
  48117, 48381, 48011, 48129, 48087, 48369, 48069, 48437, 48045, 48191,
  48075, 48017, 48279, 48189, 48153, 48345, 48101, 48155, 48197, 48487,
  48305, 48169
]);

var region1 = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: counties.filter(function(d) {return set1.has(d.id); })};
```

**My question is:** If I wish to add a name property for this region, how would I proceed? I'm thinking to declare something with the region variable, maybe something like:

```
var region1 = {type: "FeatureCollection", properties: 'Name': 'My Region', features: counties.filter(function(d) {return set1.has(d.id); })};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have...

```
properties: 'Name': 'My Region'
```

... is not a valid JavaScript Object. It should be:

```
var region1 = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    name: 'My Region',
    features: counties.filter(function(d) {
        return set1.has(d.id);
    })
};
```

Or, if you want them inside the `properties` property:

```
var region1 = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    properties: {
        name: 'My Region',
        features: counties.filter(function(d) {
            return set1.has(d.id);

        })
    }
};
```

Also, the convention in JavaScript is using lowercase for property names, so I advise you to use `name`, not `Name`.

Here is a Bostock's bl.ocks with your object, look at the console: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3fb65e6b6204e5731afc4152a35a0179/0d579d98e599cef73284c5e89b92e7fe94be42ab